# VBA Data pull from Redshift. Can't seem to pass "GO" command in Query String

Tags: excel, vba, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to pass a query string through VBA to pull data from a redshift server.

The query works fine in the DB environment, and I'm sure my DB connection is set up correctly in the VBA Code.

I'm getting this error:
Syntax Error at or near "GO";

I'm guessing its a spacing issue with the "GO" in the query and the next Select statement but I can't figure out how to work around this. Again, the query runs just fine in Aqua Data Studio.

VBA:

```
Sub LoadQuery1(intRow, intCol, strWSheet, strConnection, intConnection)

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim Rowcount As Long
Dim irows As Integer

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command


If intConnection = 14 Then
    If OpenConnection1() Then
    'Set up the command object and execute
    Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn1
        .CommandText = strConnection
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandTimeout = 0
    End With
    rsPubs.Open cmd, , , , adCmdText
    'rsPubs.Open cmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
End If
End If

irows = intRow + 1

Do While Not rsPubs.EOF
    'update header
    For i = 0 To rsPubs.Fields.Count - 1
            Worksheets(strWSheet).Cells(intRow, intCol + i) =            rsPubs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

    For i = 0 To rsPubs.Fields.Count - 1
            Worksheets(strWSheet).Cells(irows, intCol + i) =     rsPubs.Fields(i).Value
    Next i

    rsPubs.MoveNext
    irows = irows + 1


Loop


End Sub
```

SQL: (Sample)

```
 Select Distinct
sessionid
,dorderid
,userid
,customerid
,bookings
,dtmcreated

into #FinalMetrics
From #RawMetrics 

GO  /*This is the GO throwing the error.*/

select 
searchengine
,count(distinct sessionid) as Sessions
,count(distinct userid) as Visitors
,count(distinct orderid) as Orders
,cast(sum(bookings) as float)/100 as bookings
,cast(count(orderid) as float)/count(sessionid) as CR
from #FinalMetrics
Group by 
searchengine;
```

Other notes:
I tried replacing GO with a semicolon, but then the query stops before the final select statement and doesn't actually pull a recordset.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `vbCrLf` to separate your SQL statements.

For example:

```vb
Dim strSql
strSql = "select col1 from table1" & vbCrLf
strSql = strSql & "select col1 from table2"

With cmd
    ....
    .CommandText = strSql
End With
```

And then use `Recordset.NextRecordset` to load the results of your second `select` statment:

```vb
rsPubs.Open cmd, , , , adCmdText
....
rsPubs.NextRecordset
```

Comment: Good thought. I tried your suggestion just now and the same error was thrown. Maybe its not a spacing issue and there's something wrong with the GO command?

Comment: Don't use `GO`. Like in the answer above, you just want to separate your two commands with a newline (`vbCrLf`).

Comment: So that was my original approach but for some reason redshift won't pull a record set following any sort of insert/update statement without a GO in place. Not sure why this is. 

My previous code was:

    Select *
    into xyz
    From abc;

    select * 
    from xyz

But this failed to pull any recordset at all, even in Aquadata studio.

Comment: But have you tried it like I suggested above with `vbCrLf`?

Comment: Yeah just tried that with and without a GO.

`sql = c.Value & vbCrLf

sql = sql & c.Offset(1, 0).Value`

Comment: This seems to work only with `select` statements that return rows. You'll probably need to execute your commands separately. You can run your `select into` with `cmd.Execute`. No need to use a `Recordset` there.

Comment: @Fubudis: You can control the statement separator in Aqua Data Studio under File>Options>Scripts>Amazon Redshift. By default, in Aqua Data Studio, the statement separator is a "go" or "/"